# How to make text scroll and keep other elements fixed to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create the following display, where the text scrolls and the other elements are fixed to the bottom of the screen:

[image]

However, it is appearing as follows, where the text doesn't scroll and it's pushing the elements off the screen.:

[image]

This is the layout I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </ScrollView>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Don't Show Again"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroller" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingTop="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/stop"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/common_button" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgCancel"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What do I need to do to make the text scroll and the other elements fixed to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Why dont you fix the height of that dialog ?

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_above ="@+id/chkBox"` in scrollview

Comment: Other option is to set bottom margin for scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this xml code and apply images where you need

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#5555"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    </ScrollView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Don&apos;t Show Again" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingTop="0dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/imgCancel"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the ScrollView Containing the TextView inside a Layout(Linear would do). I hope it helps